# Trouble getting a file from Azure container

Tags: azure-storage, umbraco7

I am trying to get a file from Azure container. I need to read its content.

The file has been uploaded to umbraco media, media are stored in our Azure container.

Its normal (umbraco) url would be like:

```
~/media/10890/filename.xls
```

I am trying to retrieve it like this:

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["strorageconnstring"]);
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("storagemedia");
```

The thing is - I am not sure how I am supposed to retrieve a particular file? I tried:

1.

```
CloudBlobDirectory dira = container.GetDirectoryReference("10890"); // file folder within media
var list = dira2.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true).ToList(); // Returns error saying "The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server."
```

However the *10890* folder within media storage exists and I can browse it with storage browser.

2.

```
CloudBlockBlob blobFile = container.GetBlockBlobReference("10890/filename.xls");

                    string text;
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        blobFile.DownloadToStream(memoryStream); // Throws "The specifed resource name contains invalid characters." error

                        var length = memoryStream.Length;
                        text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
                    }
```

Any idea how to read the file? And what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the value of `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storagemedia"]`?

Comment: Sorry, it should be this: `var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("storagemedia");` of course. Editied the given code @Gauray

Comment: Can you share the URI property of `blobFile`?

Comment: It is weird: `https://ourazure.blob.core.windows.net/https://ourazure.blob.core.windows.net/10890/filename.xls` @Gaurav

Comment: Please check the connection string. I suspect there’s an issue there only.

Comment: The connection string was fine, the GetContainerReference parameter value was wrong. Thanks for the hint! @Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

Thank You [Gaurav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri) for providing your suggestion in comment section.

Thank You [nicornotto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1611620/nickornotto) for confirming that your issue got resolved by changing the container name reference in the below statement.

```
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("storagemedia");
```